# Published Heroku app suddenly goes "No such app" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, https

I have a Rails/Heroku app that was published somewhere in Oct 2013, and it had run for quite a while with no issues. So a day came with a "No such app" error page when I try to access the app as I used to: [clicaco.herokuapp.com](http://clicaco.herokuapp.com/).

Seems like that from that day on, Heroku started serving my app through the **https** protocol. The change was involuntary, though, and I would like to revert it back.

Heroku documentation seems to enforce the use of SLL endpoints, and so far I could not find documentation regarding my current objetive: **using the good old http**.

*- Does anyone knows the best direction to do this?*

Comment: The app loads just fine for me. It redirects me to http://clicaco.com.br/ (no https). Are you still experiencing this issue? If so, do you have any SSL related Heroku add-ons installed? You can check via `heroku addons` in your terminal.

Comment: Yeah... actually the domain went off, I haven't noticed. :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku [deprecated the Bamboo routing in the past](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing-bamboo) and removed it completely on October 20, 2014.

If your app was using the Bamboo stack, then it will not work anymore. Given the synthoms you described, it may be possible your app was using the old stack.

Heroku is not forcing https at the time being. It's likely the app stopped being routed, and the hostname is now served using the default Heroku settings.